# Is it possible to voluntarly unlist a relay from consensus?

Tags: relays, consensus

While configuring a relay I made multiple tor instances ( with different nicknames and fingerprints). Now i'm in a situation that current relay i'm hosting dont't get listed at the consensus because there are other instances listed as hibernating with same ip.

Is there a way to get those previous relays unlisted?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the tor instances your not using so there gone and not just hibernating. There is no way to remove them your self from the consensus. They will automaticly dissapear after about a week of no activity.